# convert multiple excel files to csv files with python

Tags: python, excel

Is there a way to convert multiple files?
Can I use `glob.glob`?

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,'D:/apera/Python27/xlrd-0.9.3')

import xlrd

import csv

ExcelFile = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding010.xls"
CSVFile = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding010.csv"

def Convert(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
    ws = wb.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
    csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=';')

    for rownum in xrange(ws.nrows):
         wr.writerow(
         list(x.encode('latin1')
              for x in ws.row_values(rownum)))

    csvfile.close()

Convert(ExcelFile, "INPUT", CSVFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, glob combined with os will work

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir("yourfolder")
for f in glob.glob("*.xls"):
    #call your conversion function
```

Comment: can you tell me more specific? because it give me error. because the csv files need to make it multiple. i need your help. thanks